# Необходимо проверить есть ли здесь последовательность 4 или более одинаковых цифр в списке

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно доработать программу чтобы находила 4 или более одинаковых цифр в списке,сейчас находит
4 одинаковые цифры в начале списка,нужно добавить еще один внутренний цикл что бы сначала сравнивал
первый элемент со следующими,и находил одинаковые цифры,а потом 2 ой со следующими,и т.д.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def checkio(matrix):
    row=matrix
    var_found=0
    element=0
    while element<len(row):
            if row[0]==row[element]:
              var_found+=1
              print('FAUND row[0]==row[element]',row[0],row[element])
            element+=1  
    if var_found>=4:
            print('FOUND ROW!','row:',row)
            return True 
    var_found=0  

if __name__ == '__main__':        
 checkio([1, 1, 1, 1,9]) #Так находит
 checkio([0, 1, 1, 1,1]) #Так не находит
```

Сделал такой код,который до конца не работает,не ищет скажем в середине:

```
def checkio(matrix):
    j_ryad=0
    k_element=0
    n_perebor_vlevo=0  
    var_found=0
    while j_ryad<len(matrix):
      while n_perebor_vlevo<j_ryad: 
        if matrix[n_perebor_vlevo]==matrix[k_element]:
          print('FAUND matrix[n_perebor_vlevo]==matrix[k_element]:',matrix[n_perebor_vlevo],matrix[k_element]) 
          var_found+=1 
        n_perebor_vlevo+=1     
      j_ryad+=1
    if var_found>=4:
     print('FOUND ROW!:')
     return True 
    var_found=0    

if __name__ == '__main__':        
 #checkio([1, 1, 1, 1,9]) #Так находит
 checkio([0, 1, 1, 1,1]) #Так не находит
```

Comment: Так если ты знаешь,что надо сделать,то сделай.В чем проблема?

Comment: Сделал такой код,который до конца не работает,не ищет скажем в середине:

Comment: слово matrix в заблуждение вводит (обычно для двухмерных массивов используется). Для одномерного списка чисел можно numbers имя использовать¶ Имеет значение подряд или не подряд идут одинаковые значения—следует явно упомянуть, что "последовательность" означает что подряд идут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def checkList(l):
    sl = sorted(l)
    count = 1
    for j in range(1, len(sl)):
        if sl[j] == sl[j - 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            if count >= 4:
                print("Цифра {} повторяется {} раз(а).".format(sl[j - 1], count))
            count = 1
    if count >= 4:
        print("Цифра {} повторяется {} раз(а).".format(sl[j - 1], count))

checkList([1,1,1,1,9])
checkList([0,1,1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Имеется еще такой вариант решения с помощью итератора `groupby()` из модуля `itertools` стандартной библиотеки Python:

```
from itertools import groupby


def checkio(matrix):
    row = sorted(matrix)  # sorted() можно убрать, если нужны именно идущие подряд цифры
    for number, group in groupby(row):
        count = len(list(group))
        if count >= 4:
            print(f'Цифра {number} повторяется {count} раз(а).')
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Думаю, лучше добавить в код: `from itertools import groupby`

Comment: @gil9red, да, верное замечание. Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел вариант:

```
def checkio(matrix):
    row=matrix
    var_found=0
    N=len(row)        
    for i in range(N-1): 
        for j in range(i+1,N):
            if row[i]==row[j]:
                var_found+=1
    if var_found>=4:
            print('FOUND ROW!','row:',row)
            return True 
    var_found=0  

if __name__ == '__main__':        
 checkio([1, 1, 1, 1,9]) #Так находит
 checkio([0, 1, 1, 1,1]) #Так находит
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно список цифр перевести в строку и обработать регуляркой, которая найдет последовательности от 4-х и более подряд идущих цифр:

```
import re


def checkList(l):
    text = ''.join(map(str, l))
    
    items = [match[0] for match in re.finditer(r'(\d)\1{3,}', text)]
    print(items)


checkList([1, 1, 1, 9])                    # []
checkList([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9])              # ['11111']
checkList([1, 1, 1, 1, 9])                 # ['1111']
checkList([0, 1, 1, 1, 1])                 # ['1111']
checkList([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2])  # ['1111', '2222']
```

---

**PS.** Если нужно подсчитать цифры, а они не обязаны идти подряд, тогда предварительная сортировка поможет: `text = ''.join(map(str, sorted(l)))`

**PPS.** Если нужно обработать результат и напечатать статистику:

```
def checkList(l):
    text = ''.join(map(str, l))

    items = [match[0] for match in re.finditer(r'(\d)\1{3,}', text)]
    
    # Если список не пустой
    if items:
        match = items[0]
        print("Цифра {} повторяется {} раз(а).".format(match[0], len(match)))
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить, есть ли `n` или более идущих подряд одинаковых значений в списке:

```
def n_in_a_row(seq, n):
    return any(all_equal(seq[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(seq) - n + 1))
```

это квадратичный алгоритм: `O(len(seq) * n)` по времени и `O(n)` по памяти. Здесь `all_equal(seq)` проверяет что все значения равны во входном списке:

```
def all_equal(seq):
    return all(seq[0] == item for item in seq)
```

Пример:

```
>>> n_in_a_row([1, 0, 1], 2)
False
>>> n_in_a_row([0, 1, 1], 2)
True
```

Для произвольной коллекции можно [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) использовать:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice 

def n_in_a_row(iterable, n):
    return any(sum(1 for _ in islice(same, n)) == n for _, same in groupby(iterable))
```

Это линейный однопроходной алгоритм, который выходит сразу как только `n` одинаковых элементов обнаружены—O(N) по времени, O(1) по памяти.

Ещё квадратичный вариант, как первый пример, но поддерживает не только списки, а и произвольные коллекции (к примеру, открытый файл):

```
from itertools import tee, islice

def n_in_a_row(iterable, n):
    copies = tee(iterable, n)
    for i, it in enumerate(copies):
        if i:
            next(islice(it, i-1, None))  # shift i-th copy i places
    return any(map(all_equal, zip(*copies)))
```